# Writing a custom YAML file to apply Dart fixes

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, dart-analyzer

I have a Flutter project with two Dart files. In one of the files, I have a class with a deprecated getter that I want to replace with a new one. To achieve this, I created a .fix.yaml file with the custom fix rule. However, when running dart fix --apply, the custom fix is not being applied, and the deprecated getter remains unchanged. Both files are in the same project directory, and I have verified that the .fix.yaml file and the class file are correctly formatted. What could be causing the custom fix not to work as expected? Can someone guide me on how to write this custom YAML file effectively? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
My custom yaml file and user.dart code is provided below.

user.dart file

```
class User {
  String? name;
  int? age;

  User({this.name, this.age});
  @Deprecated('Use fullName instead')
  String? get userName => fullName;
  String? get fullName => name;

  void sayHello() {
    debugPrint("Hello, my name is $name and I am $age years old.");
  }
}
```

fix_user_rename.fix.yaml file

```
version: 1
transforms:
  - title: "Replace deprecated getter userName with fullName"
    description: "Replaces usages of the deprecated getter userName with the new getter fullName."
    matcher:
      type: MethodInvocation
      where:
        name: "userName"
    generator:
      type: SimpleGenerator
      template: "fullName"
```

I tried to see how Flutter's fixes are written here.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/HEAD/packages/flutter/lib/fix_data/fix_material/fix_text_theme.yaml

and try to write custom fixes accordingly.

Comment: Are you using package:custom_lint?  I understand it simplifies writing custom lints and fixes quite a bit.

Comment: I'm not using custom lint, but I'm grateful that the information provided was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a `fix_data.yaml` file in your lib folder. Then you can define your fixes in that file. The specification of that file can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Data-driven-Fixes)

In your case this should work:

```yaml
version: 1
transforms:
  - title: Rename to fullName
    date: 2023-12-23
    bulkApply: true
    element:
      uris: [ '$$relative file import$$', '$$package file import$$' ]
      getter: 'userName'
      inClass: 'User'
    changes:
      - kind: 'rename'
        newName: 'fullName'
```

To see the fix as a hint in your IDE you might have to restart your IDE.